# Scrip execution goes on for infinite time in jenkins powershell plugin

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, qlikview

I am able to execute powershell script on machine but not able to do it using jenkins powershell plugin

My powershell script executes another program's UI (QlikView) and then closes it it works when I execute script directly on machine. But when I do the same using jenkins powershell plugin it does not work the execution goes on for infinite time.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
 param (
$FullQvwPath
 )


function qv-SaveAndClose-QVW
{
   param(
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
   $QvwPath
  )


try {

    $qvComObject = new-object -comobject QlikTech.QlikView
    $NewCreatedDoc = $qvComObject.CreateDoc()
    $NewCreatedDoc.SaveAs($QvwPath)
    $NewCreatedDoc.CloseDoc()


    $qvComObject.Quit()

}
finally {

}

}

qv-SaveAndClose-QVW -QvwPath $FullQvwPath
```

I have put above code in file - QlikSaveAndClose.ps1

.\QlikSaveAndClose.ps1 -FullQvwPath 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\Dashboard.qvw

Comment: Without showing the code it is impossible to answer this..

Comment: @Theo Sorry I was editing my question and adding script

Comment: Perhaps using a `catch{..}` block could help you figuring out what the problem could be. Also, because you are creating a Com object, it is wise to remove that from memory when done, so in the `finally {..}` block I would add `if ($qvComObject) {[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($qvComObject) | Out-Null; [System.GC]::Collect(); [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()}`

Comment: Does the Jenkins server have this comobject `QlikTech.QlikView` ?

Comment: How are you using the `try` block without the `catch` block?

Comment: `try {} finally {} `

Comment: @RohinSidharth yes  as I said I am able to execute it manually on the server but not able to do it using jenkins and I have installed jenkins on the same server so QlikView is already there installed.

Comment: This behavior is consistent with the script waiting on user input which it never gets.

Comment: @RohinSidharth But when I execute same script from power shell manually on the same server it executes successfully without asking for any user input.
So why it does not execute from jenkins powershell plugin

Comment: Can you try to run the script like this from cmd and see what is happening. Perhaps run it a couple times. `start powershell.exe -file C:\scripts\QlikSaveAndClose.ps1 -noprofile`. If no issues, you should probably talk to Jenkins support.

Comment: A friend recommended to start here: https://www.roguewave.com/blog/finding-test-failures-in-jenkins-by-replaying-test-program-execution. Apparently, you can also use PyCharm to debug Jenkins. Perhaps you can do some research in that direction too.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the file already exists? In that case `SaveAs` is prompting to overwrite the file. So, remove it first. Also place the `Quit` in the finally so the comobject is always closed, even on errors. And while we're at it, only use approved *Verb-Noun* names for your cmdlets:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String] $FullQvwPath
)

function Save-QVW
{
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [String] $Path
    )

    $qvComObject = New-Object -ComObject "QlikTech.QlikView"
    try 
    {
        $newCreatedDoc = $qvComObject.CreateDoc()
        if (Test-Path -Path $Path)
        {
            Remove-Item -Path $Path -Force
        }
        $newCreatedDoc.SaveAs($Path)
        $newCreatedDoc.CloseDoc()
    }
    finally 
    {
        $qvComObject.Quit()
    }
}

Save-QVW -Path $FullQvwPath
```

Comment: No it does not ask to override it directly overrides it I have already tried that.